# Extreme points of the closed unit sphere in $\big(C_K([0,1]),\|\;\|_\infty\big)$

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, convex-analysis

Lets take $(C_K([0,1]),\|\|_\infty)$, which is a normed vector space.
$$
C_K([0,1])=\{x:[0,1]\to K\;\;|\;x\text{  is continuous  } \}\\
\|x\|_\infty=\sup_{t\in[0,1]}|x(t)|
$$
So, since the closed unit sphere is $\overline B_1(0)=\{x\in C_K([0,1]):\|x\|_\infty\le 1\}$, I've only get that the extreme points of $\overline B_1(0)$ are functions $f(t)$ s.t. $f(t)\in[-1,1]\;\forall t\in[0,1]$, but can't figure out how to describe them better. Any ideas for a more detailed description of these extreme points would be appreciated.

Comment: What does continuity give you?

Comment: That every continuous function in $[0,1]$ reaches its maximum value

Comment: If a continuous real-valued function takes on only two values, at most, what possibilities are there for it?

Comment: Being like a polynomial?